# Are there any disadvantages of writing !string.isEmpty()?

Tags: java, string, coding-style, if-statement

In if-statements in Java code i often read something like `if(string != null && string.isEmpty() == false)`. I was used to write `if(string != null && !string.isEmpty())`

Are there any disadvantages of using `!string.isEmpty()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In terms of behaviour

```
if(string != null && string.isEmpty() == false)
```

and

```
if(string != null && !string.isEmpty())
```

are obviously identical. I prefer the latter, only because it's slightly more concise. Where possible, I prefer to express conditions positively, but unfortunately there is no `string.isNotEmpty()` method

So in general when I want to check if a String is either null or empty (in a null-safe fashion) I use:

```
StringUtils.isNotBlank(string)
```

This StringUtils class is from the Apache commons lang library, but you can easily write your own if you don't already have this on your classpath and don't want to add it.

Comment: I left out the null check because i thought it does not matter here. But now i updated my question. BTW: I am considering to use StringUtils.

Comment: Could you please update your answer to fit to my question edit? (i added null handling). I tried to edit your answer, but that was not accepted

Comment: I edited it again (my edit from yesterday was not accepted, or have been lost otherwise)

Answer (score 3):

There aren't any disadvantages I can think of. It's just a matter of personal coding style and preference. Personally I would also prefer `if(!string.isEmpty())`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I find the ! harder to read. You have to make a mental note that what is about to come next needs to be negated. The if(string.isEmpty() == false), doesn't require any mental notes. As such I think it's less likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: `... == false` is good approach for environments without syntax highliting.

Answer (score 0):

The below is snippet from [java.lang.String implementation](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html)

```
1286       public boolean isEmpty() {
1287           return 0 == count;
1288       }
```

`isEmpty()` check whether the number of symbols in the string, stored in the private field count, is 0. It shouldn't matter if you use `if(string.isEmpty() == false)` or `if(!string.isEmpty())`, more of a personal coding preference. 
However, If you need to perform the null check on String as well, you can check [Apache Commons-Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) `StringUtils.isEmpty(..)`